# Downloading an image being cached and showing in my imageview

Tags: xamarin

I need to download an image where it saves in the cache using Imageview, somehow for me to do it in a simple way ?

I can download it as you can see below more in not saved in cache

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }

    //-----------

        **Show image**
        var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("URL");
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android: using imageView.SetImage(uri) [find here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.ImageView.SetImageURI/p/Android.Net.Uri/)

iOS:SDWebImage [find here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sdwebimage)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Example :-

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage)
                .Retry(3, 200)
                .DownSample(300, 300)
                .Transform(new CircleTransformation())
                .Transform(new GrayscaleTransformation())
                .LoadingPlaceholder(Config.LoadingPlaceholderPath, ImageSource.ApplicationBundle)
                .ErrorPlaceholder(Config.ErrorPlaceholderPath, ImageSource.ApplicationBundle)
.Into(_imgDisplay);
```